# Add default value to select list in laravel form

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-blade

I want to retrieve database values in category name and i want to show default value in selection. 
This is my controller for my edit view

```
public function edit($id)
    {
        $account = Account::findOrFail($id);

        $banks = Bank::all();       

        return view('account.edit', compact(['account', 'banks']));
    }
```

but in banks category i get it from banks model. this is not showing default value in my edit view selection.

This is my edit view selection

```
 <div class="form-group">
    <label for="bank_id">Bank</label>
        <select class="form-control" name="bank_id">
            @if(!empty($banks))
                @foreach($banks as $bank)
                <option value="{{ $bank->id }}">{{ $bank->name }}</option>
                @endforeach
            @endif
        </select>
</div>
```

I used edit button for pass id to my controller

```
<a class="btn btn btn-secondary" href="{{route('account.edit', $account->id)}}"><span class="fa fa-pencil"></span> Edit</a>
```

Comment: Set previously selected bank as default what's the problem ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try This Way. Hope it will work.

```
<option value="{{$bank->id}}" {{$account->bank_id==$bank->id ? 'selected' : ''}}>{{$bank->name}}</option>
```